# QByteArray:: append() leads to memory reallocation

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-memory-allocation, qbytearray

I have noticed that in some cases after executing the following code

```
void appendToArray(QByteArray &array, const char *source, int size) {
    void *p1 = array.data();
    array.append(dest, size);
    void *p2 = array.data();
}
```

p1 and p2 become different. But I always thought that append() method doesn't affect inner QByteArray memory "at the beginning" - it just appends some bytes to the end of object; Am I wrong?

Comment: You can use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#reserve to avoid relocation if you know estimate size of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the QByteArray doc page (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html)

> When you append() data to a non-empty array, the array will be
>   reallocated and the new data copied to it.

This may not happen all of the time, as the array may have enough memory allocated to store the new item. However, when it needs to get more space to store more data, it reallocates memory for the entire array and copies the existing data across. This is so that it can maintain a single contiguous data array.

Comment: I do not know how much space I need in advance, how do I mitigate that memory relocation problem with QByteArray or any other compatible binary data structure you might kindly suggest to use. P.S I might have the need to incrementally allocate huge amount of binary data and performance is of the essence ?

Comment: If your data doesn't need to be contiguous you could use something like the `std:deque` container. This allocates blocks of data as it needs to and doesn't cause reallocations and moves. If you do need to use QByteArray, then you could just take a guess at how much you need and use `reserve`.

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to assume the pointer will not change on `append()`.

`QByteArray` preallocates some amount of space after the data, but after the amount exceeds, it uses `realloc`, which can or can not just extend the data buffer depending on free memory existence after the buffer.

If there is no free memory left after the buffer, it will allocate a new chunk of memory for you, so the pointer in question will change.

**UPD**: As *N1ghtLight* mentioned in comments, you can rely on the pointer position in case you use [`reserve()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#reserve) method to allocate enough memory before doing `append()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I always thought that append() method doesn't affect inner QByteArray memory "at the beginning" - it just appends some bytes to the end of object; Am I wrong?

You are right, in a way. `append()` doesn't the affect the **contents** of the beginning of the array data. But it can (and it must) sometimes **move** the unchanged data to a bigger block.

Just because `data()` has changed doesn't mean that the *contents* have changed!